# Get paragraphs after headings with simple_html_dom in Laravel

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I use the voku/simple_html_dom parser in Laravel.

When I have the following HTML:

```
<h2>Title 1</h2>
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
<h2>Title 2</h2>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
  <p>Text 5</p>
```

I would like to get it in a array like:

```
[
'Title 1' => array('Text 1','Text 2'),
'Title 2' => array('Text 3','Text 4','Text 5'),
]
```

So I tried:

```
 $array = [];
 $text = '<h2>Title 1</h2>
            <p>Text 1</p>
            <p>Text 2</p>
           <h2>Title 2</h2>
            <p>Text 3</p>
            <p>Text 4</p>
            <p>Text 5</p>';
  $text = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($text);
  foreach($text -> find('h2') as $element) {
       $paragraphs = [];
       foreach($element->next_sibling('p') AS $paragraph) {
            $paragraphs[] = $paragraph->plaintext;
       }
       $array[$element->plaintext] = $paragraphs;
  }
```

But I only get the first paragraph.

How do I get all the paragraphs under a heading till the next heading?

Comment: Please be aware that Symfony has a better written and supported DOM parser: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Comment: Can I add that to a Laravel framework?

Comment: You can add anything with composer.  Laravel is built mainly from Symfony components already.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in your example, are all at the same level.

So if you match the `h2` and loop all the siblings that are `p` elements, you will get 2 times `Text 3`, `Text 4`, `Text 5` as they are siblings from the first and the second `h2` element.

One approach could be getting all the paragraphs and stop when encountering an `h2` element to not get duplicate matches.

```
$array = [];
foreach($text -> find('h2') as $element) {
    $h2Text = $element->text();
    $sib = $element->next_sibling();
    while($sib) {        
        if ($sib->nodeName() === "h2") break;
        if ($sib->nodeName() === "p") {
            $array[$h2Text][] = $sib->text();
        }
        $sib = $sib->next_sibling();
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Title 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Text 1
            [1] => Text 2
        )

    [Title 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Text 3
            [1] => Text 4
            [2] => Text 5
        )

)
```